# How can I boost the music volume higher than the max limit?

Tags: audio, volume-control, samsung-galaxy-gio

I have a Samsung Galaxy running Android. When I put music to max, it's not loud enough in my ear phone.

How can I boost it beyond the maximum volume? On Linux I can do this with ALSA; is there a way to do it in Android?

**Follow up:**

All of them are paid media players so FREE is almost unavailable. Using for the moment: [Cubed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.abrantix.rockon.rockonnggl&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm9yZy5hYnJhbnRpeC5yb2Nrb24ucm9ja29ubmdnbCJd)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know audio amplifying circuits will have a fixed amplifying ratio (gain). By adding resistance (either digitally or using analog POT) on the input (or output?) signal the volume is reduced. Hence in my opinion it can't be done.

Switching over to in ear phone buds like:[image]
instead of: [image] will provide better noise isolation and there by improve listening experience.  If the music is being played from files stored in the phone, you can edit them to increase volume with audio editing tools like [Audacity](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://audacity.sourceforge.net/&ei=821yUP7hKMryrQegxYCIBA&usg=AFQjCNEjZ2LIXUq09FvorQJKXfovOmNfWg&sig2=OnYgv-qM3zqd-2uK_r51pw).

Comment: GT-S5660 - i am using. I downloaded some apps speaker boost but its not enough.

Comment: I downloaded, Poweramp media player which has extra EQ and effects works great, and two other speaker booster software. Problem resolved. And with your guide i will fire and rock more sound on my ear thanks a lot!!

Comment: All the best to your auditory nerves ;-)

Comment: @YumYumYum Don't forget that these in-ear buds often have a max output of 80 to 110dB. Since they're in your ear canal, that 110dB is an effective 110dB. Just be warned that you can easily get permanent hearing disorders if you don't watch out with these.